# How I can fix NoMethodError in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, nomethoderror

I write a multiplayer game(snake) with backend based on Ruby. This function must receive commands for frontend and send the current state of the game. But throw NoMethod error on the four line of my function for the changeside method and I don't know why because of that class method is present.

Class method example

```
  def changeside(nump,newSide)
     opp = {'R':'L','U':'D','D':'U','L':'R'}
     cx = {'L':-1,'R':1,'U':0,'D':0}
     cx = {'L':0,'R':0,'U':-1,'D':1}
     if newSide!=opposite[players[nump]['side']] && ['R','L','U','D'].count( newSide)==1
       players[nump]['side']['cx'] = cx[newSide]
       players[nump]['side']['cy'] = cy[newSide]
     end

  end
```

Error example

```
2020-10-07 18:01:23 - NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
```

The function I'm run

```
def getStatus(game)
      ans = {"opStatus"=>TRUE}
      puts game
      $games[game['gid'.to_i]]['game'].changeside(2,game['side'])
      $games[game['gid'.to_i]]['game'].move(($games[game['gid']]['fid']==game['pid']?1:2))
      ans["gameStatus"] = $games[game['id']]['game'].run
      ans['timer'] = $games[game['id']]['game'].timer
      ans['snake'] = $games[game['id']][($games[game['id']]['fid']==game['pid']?1:2)].snake
      ans['enemy'] = $games[game['id']][($games[game['id']]['fid']==game['pid']?2:1)].snake
      ans['food'] = $games[game['id']]['game'].food
    end
```

Here is JSON sent to the function

```
{"gid"=>"1", "side"=>"R", "pid"=>"1"}
```

To fix that, I debugged that moment, but I couldn't go inside a class method.
Here is the full code of the class game.
It located in another file and called by

```
`require_relative 'game.rb'`
```

Full code of the class.

```
class Game
  attr_accessor :players, :food, :walls, :timer, :run,:winner

  def initialize()
    @players = {}
    @winner = -1
    @players[1] = {'snake'=>[[9,2],[8,2],[7,2]]}
    @players[1]['cx'] = 0
    @players[1]['cy'] = -1
    @players[1]['side'] = 'U'
    @players[2] = {'snake'=>[[2,9],[2,8],[2,7]]}
    @players[2]['cx'] = -1
    @players[2]['cy'] = 0
    @players[2]['side'] = 'L'
    @timer = 0
    @run = FALSE

    genFood
  end
  def genFood()
    @food = [rand(10)+1,rand(10)+1]
    while  players[1]['snake'].include?(food) || players[2]['snake'].include?(food)
      @food = [rand(10)+1,rand(10)+1]
    end
  end

  def move(nump)

    if @run
      @timer+=0.25
      @players[nump]['snake'].shift
      @players[nump]['snake'].push([@players[id]['snake'][0]+@players[id]['cx'],@players[id]['snake'][1]+@players[id]['cy']])
      if @players[nump]['snake'][0] == food
        @players[nump]['snake'][0].unshift(food)
        @food = [rand(10)+1,rand(10)+1]
        while  players[nump]['snake'].include(food) or players[1]['snake'].include(food)
          @food = [rand(10)+1,rand(10)+1]
        end
      end
      if @player[nump]['snake'].count(@player[nump]['snake'][-1])==2 ||
          @winner = ((nump==1)?2:1)
      elsif @players[((nump==1)?2:1)]['snake'].count(@player[nump]['snake'][-1])==1
        @winner = 0
      else
        if @timer==60
          if @players[1]['snake'].length()>@players[2]['snake'].length()
            @winner = 1
          elsif @players[1]['snake'].length()<@players[2]['snake'].length()
            winner = 2
          else
            winner = 0
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def changeside(nump,newSide)
    opp = {'R':'L','U':'D','D':'U','L':'R'}
    cx = {'L':-1,'R':1,'U':0,'D':0}
    cx = {'L':0,'R':0,'U':-1,'D':1}
    if newSide!=opposite[players[nump]['side']] && ['R','L','U','D'].count( newSide)==1
      players[nump]['side']['cx'] = cx[newSide]
      players[nump]['side']['cy'] = cy[newSide]
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I count 137 calls to `[]` in your code, and all you are telling is that you are getting an error at one of those 137 places. There is no way that anybody is going to be able to figure out what is wrong, without you *significantly* reducing the amount of code, and being *a lot* more precise about the exact error.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I wrote that error is on calling changeside method in function getStatus(line 4)

Comment: There's still three calls to `[]` on that line. Which of the three causes the error?

Comment: No method `opposite` has been defined.